# Russian encoding not consistent on mail.ru with phpmailer

Tags: php, encoding, phpmailer

Im sending automated emails to Russian users, i used utf-8 encoding and when they open in gmail it shows perfect, in outlook it shows incorrect but in mail.ru which is a popular email account for Russian users it shows up as gobblygook.

So we sent an email from outlook in accryllic to mail.ru and it showed the same content without problem, i then changed the encoding to windows-1251, again it shows up fine in gmail but in mail.ru (who dont have an option i could find to switch encoding and dont support UTF-8) it shows as a different type of gooblygook.

Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=koi8-r" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.2/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();


$body = "Это письмо отправлено потому. This is english";




$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "xxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');

$mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@gmail.com","xxx");

$mail->Subject    = "Urgent";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address1 = "xxx@mail.ru";
$address2 = "xxx@gmail.com";


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Surely there is a way to send a Russian message to mail.ru, im obviously doing something stupid cause even sending from outlook as acryllic works but maybe i have to put encoding somewhere else other than header.

My Plan was it would auto encode the message but since they dont support UTF-8 my new plan is to display a message saying "click here to view this message in a webpage" in Russian and then i can control the encoding myself and it will display fine but i cant even figure out how to send the Russian message to mail.ru because it all displays in gobblygook for win-1251,UTF-8 and even kio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charset you set in an HTML header will have absolutely **NO** effect on the php code running later in the same script. PHP couldn't care less about client-side charsets, until the client sends some data back to php. You need to generate a proper MIME email, and set the proper charsets in the headers for that.

I'd strongly suggest using PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both which make sending MIME emails trivial, and far far easier and more reliable than utter garbage that is PHP's `mail()` function.

Comment: naive question but i thought i was using phpmailer, is my code messed up that im reference php mailer but not using phpmailer to actually send it?

Comment: sorry, yes, you're using it properly. force of habit. far too many questions on the site with people abusing mail() to send attachments and whatnot. but the stuff about the headers remains. you have to set an email header, not an html output header.

Comment: Ok thanks, your comment put me on the right path, i simply added:

$mail->CharSet = 'windows-1251';

directly under $mail = new PHPMailer();

Now it works fine on gmail,english systems,russian systems and also mail.ru. So i guess a good question would be why would i use UTF-8 instead of this, im guessing it has limitations so luckily enough i know if the user is Russian before i send it so i will send windows-1251 only if i know its russian

Answer (score 0):

You can also add:

$mail->SetLanguage("ru","phpmailer/language");

It works with or without but enforces when sending in Russian I have found.